# How does /sys/dev/char get populated in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, driver, kernel-module

I'm learning to write a simple kernel module that implements `open, read, write, close, ioctl` syscalls for reading/writing in kernel memory (something like a shared memory / IPC demo).

I used to call `mknod` for binding the major/minor number allocated by the driver with a character file. But I questioned myself about why we aren't always required to manually do so when we attach an USB pendrive to the system, and I discovered `udev`.

I know how to use `kobject_init_and_add()` and `kobject_uevent()` to create a node in `sysfs` tree and notify `udev`, but while exploring `/sys` folder I noticed the `/sys/dev/char` folder, that contains symlinks to devices, named like `major:minor`. I don't understand why I can't find here the major/minor couple of my driver... Am I supposed to manually do something else from inside the module?

How can I find a full-but-simple example on how to properly describe and handle my "virtual" device in the sysfs tree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading Chapter 4 of "*Linux device driver development*" by *John Madieu*, I discovered that it was easier than what I thought:

all you need in order to automatically instantiate the proper character device abstractions in `/sys` and `/dev` is to create a `struct class` with the help of `class_create(...)` function, and then use `device_create(...)`.

Effects:
assuming you have a class called `my_class` and call the device `my_device` with major number `xx` and minor number `yy`,

- `/sys/class/my_class` folder is created;
- `/sys/devices/virtual/my_class/my_device` folder is created;
- `/sys/class/my_class/my_device` symlink points to `/sys/class/my_class/my_device`;
- `/sys/dev/char/xx:yy` symlink points to `/sys/class/my_class/my_device`;
- `/dev/my_device` character device is created (so no more `mknod` calls);

The `/sys/class/my_class/my_device` folder is quite interesting. It has:

- `dev` file: it contains `major:minor` number;
- `uevent` file: if you write `add` in it, the kernel will re-emit `add` uevents; uevents are used to signal a userspace daemon like `udev` about creation/modification/removal of a kernel object in the sysfs tree;
- `subsystem` symlink: it points back to `/sys/class/my_class`;
- `power` folder: probably some interfaces for stuff like [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/runtime_pm.txt).

**Always remember to match every *_create call with a *destroy call in the exit function of the module.**

*`class_create`, `class_destroy`, `device_create`, `device_destroy` are declared in `include/linux/device.h` and defined respectively in `drivers/base/class.c` and `drivers/base/core.c` (paths in kernel source tree). There's good documentation in those source files.*